# Event Listener is not detecting more than 2 buttons (key presses) at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

I've coded 10 buttons and mapped them with keycodes to keyboard keypress events.

1-9 on the Keyboard (or numpad) are mapped to 1-9 buttons and 0 is button 10

*You must focus (click on) the body for these to function

The Problem:
If i button bash the number keys in a random way they seem ok but if i hold 2 of them down and try and press a third, the third does not register.

The Code:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  const {
    key,
    keyCode,
    metaKey,
    shiftKey,
    altKey,
    ctrlKey
  } = e;
  //assigned needed keys
  //Buzzer 1 = Keyboard Or Numpad 1  
  if (e.code === "Numpad1" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit1" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b1");
    buttonaction.click();
    buttonaction.classList.add("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = true;

    //Buzzer 2 = Keyboard Or Numpad 2  
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad2" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit2" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b2");
    buttonaction.click();
    buttonaction.classList.add("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = true;

    //Buzzer 3 = Keyboard Or Numpad 3  
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad3" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit3" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b3");
    buttonaction.click();
    buttonaction.classList.add("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = true;

    //Buzzer 4 = Keyboard Or Numpad 4 
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad4" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit4" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b4");
    buttonaction.click();
    buttonaction.classList.add("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = true;

    //Buzzer 5 = Keyboard Or Numpad 5 
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad5" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit5" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b5");
    buttonaction.click();
    buttonaction.classList.add("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = true;

    //Buzzer 6 = Keyboard Or Numpad 6 
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad6" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit6" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b6");
    buttonaction.click();
    buttonaction.classList.add("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = true;

    //Buzzer 7 = Keyboard Or Numpad 7
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad7" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit7" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b7");
    buttonaction.click();
    buttonaction.classList.add("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = true;

    //Buzzer 8 = Keyboard Or Numpad 8 
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad8" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit8" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b8");
    buttonaction.click();
    buttonaction.classList.add("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = true;

    //Buzzer 9 = Keyboard Or Numpad 9
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad9" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit9" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b9");
    buttonaction.click();
    buttonaction.classList.add("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = true;

    //Buzzer 10 = Keyboard Or Numpad 10 
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad0" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit0" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b10");
    buttonaction.click();
    buttonaction.classList.add("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = true;



  } else {
    preventdefault(e);
  }
});


//key ups
window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const {
    key,
    keyCode,
    metaKey,
    shiftKey,
    altKey,
    ctrlKey
  } = e;


  //assigned needed keys
  //Buzzer/Player 1 = Keyboard Number 1   
  if (e.code === "Numpad1" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit1" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b1");
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction.classList.remove("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = false;

    //Buzzer/Player 2 = Keyboard Number 2   
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad2" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit2" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b2");
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction.classList.remove("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = false;

    //Buzzer/Player 3 = Keyboard Number 3   
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad3" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit3" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b3");
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction.classList.remove("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = false;

    //Buzzer/Player 4 = Keyboard Number 4   
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad4" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit4" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b4");
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction.classList.remove("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = false;

    //Buzzer/Player 5 = Keyboard Number 5   
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad5" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit5" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b5");
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction.classList.remove("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = false;

    //Buzzer/Player 6 = Keyboard Number 6   
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad6" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit6" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b6");
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction.classList.remove("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = false;

    //Buzzer/Player 7 = Keyboard Number 7   
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad7" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit7" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b7");
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction.classList.remove("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = false;

    //Buzzer/Player 8 = Keyboard Number 8   
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad8" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit8" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b8");
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction.classList.remove("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = false;

    //Buzzer/Player 9 = Keyboard Number 9   
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad9" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit9" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b9");
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction.classList.remove("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = false;

    //Buzzer/Player 10 = Keyboard Number 10   
  } else if (e.code === "Numpad0" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY" || e.code === "Digit0" && e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    buttonaction = document.getElementById("b10");
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonaction.classList.remove("buzzeractive");
    buttonaction.disabled = false;

  } else {
    preventdefault(e);
  }
});



function preventdefault(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName == "BODY") {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.code + " button press prevented");
  }
}

function p1click() {
  //action for p1 click goes here
}

function p2click() {
  //action for p1 click goes here
}

function p3click() {
  //action for p1 click goes here
}

function p4click() {
  //action for p1 click goes here
}

function p5click() {
  //action for p1 click goes here
}

function p6click() {
  //action for p1 click goes here
}

function p7click() {
  //action for p1 click goes here
}

function p8click() {
  //action for p1 click goes here
}

function p9click() {
  //action for p1 click goes here
}

function p10click() {
  //action for p1 click goes here
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.buttonscontain {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left 10px;
  margin-right 10px;
}

.buzzers {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font: normal normal normal 50px/1.1 "Black Ops One", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 158px 142px;
  background-size: 158px 142px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 16px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 14px 0 0 #000000, 4px 8px 15px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 5px 1px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, 5px -4px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, -2px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 1px 16px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 14px 0 0 #000000, 4px 8px 15px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 5px 1px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, 5px -4px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, -2px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: all 40ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.04);
  -moz-transition: all 40ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.04);
  -o-transition: all 40ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.04);
  transition: all 40ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.04);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(35deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) translateY(15px) translateZ(40px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(35deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) translateY(15px) translateZ(40px);
  transform: rotateX(35deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) translateY(15px) translateZ(40px);
  outline: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Old versions of Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}

.buzzers:active,
.buzzeractive {
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 5px 8px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 7px 0 0 #000000, 1px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 3px 1px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, 3px -6px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, -1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 8px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 7px 0 0 #000000, 1px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 3px 1px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, 3px -6px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, -1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  -webkit-transition: all 40ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 40ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -o-transition: all 40ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: all 40ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}

.b1 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.b2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.b3 {
  background-color: red;
}

.b4 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.b5 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.b6 {
  background-color: grey;
}

.b7 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.b8 {
  background-color: white;
}

.b9 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.b10 {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonscontain">
  <button id="b1" class="buzzers b1" onclick="p1click();">1</button>
  <button id="b2" class="buzzers b2" onclick="p2click();">2</button>
  <button id="b3" class="buzzers b3" onclick="p3click();">3</button>
  <button id="b4" class="buzzers b4" onclick="p4click();">4</button>
  <button id="b5" class="buzzers b5" onclick="p5click();">5</button>
  <button id="b6" class="buzzers b6" onclick="p6click();">6</button>
  <button id="b7" class="buzzers b7" onclick="p7click();">7</button>
  <button id="b8" class="buzzers b8" onclick="p8click();">8</button>
  <button id="b9" class="buzzers b9" onclick="p9click();">9</button>
  <button id="b10" class="buzzers b10" onclick="p10click();">10</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you think that holding 3 number keys down simultaneously would do anything? When is this ever done?

Comment: Many keyboards and operating systems limit the number of simultaneous keys they'll process.

Comment: Also, not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the amount of nearly identical code repeated over and over screams for a function with arguments that can call out to another helper function that contains the code that never changes.

Comment: You're allowed to combo up to several keys, ghosting however occurs on many keyboards. The question however is why is their program bugging. I think the issue is you are awaiting a release so combo detection isn't setup properly.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Its not so much I want plus 3 held at the same time, more that I need that if they are held they don't stop the others being pressed. Good tip regarding the functions with arguments, I am 100 percent self taught with coding, so just have to code what I know but understand what you are saying and it makes sense.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I coded it to wait for release because without this when a button is held it rapid fires (rather than just trigger once) so I coded it to wait for release before allowing the same button to be triggered again.